# Touching django wsgi file to reload doesn't work well

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

Touching django wsgi file doesn't reload.

so I restart apache to reflect changes instead of touch wsgi file.

below is version of each software.

```
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.1 Django/1.4
```

But Django/1.3.1 is work as well.

Is there any conflict with Django/1.4 among these?

any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html

Answer (score 2):

You must ensure you are using daemon mode of mod_wsgi.

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/why-are-you-using-embedded-mode-of.html

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode

Double check that you are.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am using daemon mode of mod_wsgi like below.

  WSGIDaemonProcess abc.jp user=webuser group=webuser processes=8 threads=16 home=/ maximum-requests=2000 shutdown-timeout=30
  WSGIProcessGroup abc.jp

I think Django1.4 might have any problem..

Comment: Django shouldn't have anything to do with it. Set LogLevel to into in Apache and mod_wsgi will log what it is doing. Do note that reload only occurs on next request, not when you touch the file.

Comment: I will try your advice and then report about it! Thank you again!